# Angular4 Server Side Rendering with Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular

I follow the Angular4 server side tutorial here *(the official stories)*
 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering , however, it is based on `CommonJs`, does anyone know how to host it on a `NodeJs` server? The tutorial does not include any information related to "hosting" with `NodeJs`, can somebody guide me how to do that? How to setup the environment in Ubuntu? How to create a `server.js` file which serves the app?

I manage to build a server app, but I don't know how to host it on server, keep having errors related to module not found. Please help.

This is the tutorial server.js (is it compatible to node.js)?

```
// Load zone.js for the server.
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');

// Import renderModuleFactory from @angular/platform-server.
var renderModuleFactory = require('@angular/platform-server').renderModuleFactory;

// Import the AOT compiled factory for your AppServerModule.
// This import will change with the hash of your built server bundle.
var AppServerModuleNgFactory = require('./dist-server/main.988d7a161bd984b7eb54.bundle').AppServerModuleNgFactory;

// Load the index.html file.
var index = require('fs').readFileSync('./src/index.html', 'utf8');

// Render to HTML and log it to the console.
renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {document: index, url: '/'}).then(html => console.log(html));
```

I am getting the error...

```
Error: Cannot find module 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    ... ... ...
```

My directory structure is as such:

```
/var/www/example.com/public_html
    dist/
    dist-server/
    node_modules/
    server.js
```

I am aware that '`zone.js/dist/zone-node`' is not available, however, even if I change to '`node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js`', some similar error will appear too... Shouldn't be the `nodeJs` able to recognize the '`zone.js/dist/zone-node`' path, I believe there is a config file for that, but where to find?

I wish somebody can **provide us with a complete tutorial** related to **Angular4 server side rendering**, I can't really find a working tutorial for weeks... please help.